# Spring @Autowired Failed

Tags: spring-data-jpa

When I try to inject my service class using  @Autowired, I faced some problem

My Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/SettlementType")
public class SettlementTypeController extends  Abstract4EyeController<SettlementTypeAudit, SettlementType, Integer>{
@Autowired
@Qualifier("settlementTypeService")
SettlementTypeService service;

@Override
public Abstract4EyeService<SettlementTypeAudit, SettlementType, Integer> get4EyeService() {
    return service;
}
}
```

My service:

```
@Service("settlementTypeService")
public class SettlementTypeService extends Abstract4EyeService<SettlementTypeAudit, SettlementType, Integer> implements IMasterFileUpload<SettlementTypeAudit, SettlementType, Integer>
{
    @Autowired
    SettlementTypeAuditRepository auditRepository;
    //my implementations
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IMasterFileUpload <AuditModel extends Base4Eye,  MainModel extends ReadOnlyEntity, ID extends Serializable> {

public List<MainModel> getMainFromCollection(List<Map<String, String>> collection);
}
```

Abstract4EyeService:

```
public abstract class Abstract4EyeService<AuditModel extends Base4Eye, MainModel extends ReadOnlyEntity, ID extends Serializable> {
 @JsonIgnore
 public abstract MainModel getMainEntity(AuditModel auditModel);
}
```

My Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settlementTypeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService field project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at project.test.genie.config.BootConfig.main(BootConfig.java:12)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService field project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService field project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:557)
... 18 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'settlementTypeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService field project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at project.test.genie.config.BootConfig.main(BootConfig.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService field project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService field project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:557)
... 18 more
```

I tried to Inject Settlementype Service, but it throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set project.test.rms.service.SettlementTypeService field project.test.rms.controller.SettlementTypeController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102 exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having problem autowiring `SettlementTypeService` is because Spring creates a proxy of that class internally. To work around this, you can create an interface to be implemented by `SettlementTypeService` and autowire with that interface in your controller.

Comment: Thanks. And I have one more doubt. If `SettlementTypeService` implements more than one interface ,then how to autowire.

Comment: @Manikandan If that is the case, then you can autowire same bean with different interfaces.